JaasConfig wrongly parse app configuration when password contain ":" character
I've an issue with SASL authentication which using JaasConfig config to build login connection string
my connection string look like <ScramLoginModule> required username=<username> password=<password>;
It seems working well if the password is not contains : character, I'm not quite sure if any others
Here is how JaasConfig parse the configuration


Please help to investigate and any suitable workaround. I tried to escape by backslash but no luck
Thanks!

Resolved it by use \"<password>\"
